# Unity2D move object up and back down with smooth transition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(I'm a beginner so please have patience with me).

**How it needs to happend:**

I have a player that can jump and hit a tile, on collision the tile with move a fixed distance up and come back down with a smooth transition.

[image]

**What I have so far:**
I am detecting the collision now there's only the matter of moving the tile up and down.

**The catch**

The tiles are suspended in air so basically they either don't have a RigidBody2D or they have one with gravity scale 0

**What I've tried**

Basically I've tried 2 solutions:

(I'm not limited to these 2, I want to implement the solution that is correct so I am open to other ideas)

1. I was thinking to simply take the current position, calculate another vector with another position, and lerp to the new position and then lerp back to the initial one.

   ```
        Vector2 initialPosition = transform.position;
        Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(initialPosition.x + 4f, initialPosition.y + 4f);
        print("Initial position: " + initialPosition);
        print("Target position: " + targetPosition);
        Vector2.Lerp(initialPosition, targetPosition, 1f);
   ```
2. I tried adding a rigidbody with scale 0

   ```
        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Jumping = false;
            anim.SetInteger("State", 0);

        }

        // print("Colision layer: " + collision.collider.gameObject.layer);

        if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == Mathf.Log(layerMask.value, 2))
        {

            GameObject Tile = collision.gameObject;
            Rigidbody2D rigidBody = Tile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rigidBody.gravityScale = 1;
            rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10f), ForceMode2D.Force);
            StartCoroutine(MoveTileWithForce(rigidBody));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveTileWithForce(Rigidbody2D TileRigidBody)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        TileRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, -5f), ForceMode2D.Force);
        TileRigidBody.gravityScale = 0;
        print("END MY COROUTINE, gravityScale: " + TileRigidBody.gravityScale);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way you can achieve this is in this simple way:

### **1**

Make sure you have a **box collider** for your character and a **Rigidbody** and the same for the block you wanna move. For both of the colliders set on **trigger**. If you want to have another collider for the player in order to make him touch the ground or hit enemies you can add another **box collider**, but make sure you have one on trigger on his head

### **2**

Add a script to the block you wanna move and also a **tag** to the player, for example `"player"`

### **3**

Inside of this new script check if the block is triggering the player:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision other)
{
if(other.compareTag("player"))
{ StartCoroutine(MovingBlock(0.5f, transform.position, upperPosition));}
|
```

It will enter inside the **if** when the player touches the block, it will start a coroutine that I will now write so you will understand the **0.5f** and the other variables

```
IEnumerator MovingBlock(float time, Vector2 startpos, Vector2 endpos)
{
    
            float elapsedTime = 0;

                while (elapsedTime < time)
                {
                    transform.position= Vector2.Lerp(startpos, endpos, (elapsedTime / time));
                    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

                    yield return null;
            }

          elapsedTime = 0f;

            while (elapsedTime < time)
                {
                    transform.position= Vector2.Lerp(endpos, startpos, (elapsedTime / time));
                    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

                    yield return null;
            }
}
```

Basically, the **Coroutine** will move the object from `startpos` to `endpos` and then back again in the amount of time that you decide (in this case 0.5 seconds). I have used the Vector2 variable `upperposition` and it's just the height you want to reach with the platform.

If you want, you can also add inside the coroutine some `yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait)` and make the platform wait in a certain position the amount of seconds you want (timeToWait)

Comment: Hello Leoverload, thank you for your helped. Your solution needed some small changes but overall put me on the right track to achive my goal. I will add another comment later today with the changes I've made.

Comment: perfect @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Vector2 initialPosition` at the beginning of your class.

On `Start()` of the tile object you should get the `initialPosition = transform.position`.

And in the `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)` you could start a coroutine to bring the tile back down.

So for example:

Player Script:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    //Initialize the rigidbody on the editor.

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 1000f));
        }
    }
}
```

And the tile script:

```
public class MyTile : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    Vector2 initialPosition;
    float speed = 2f; //the speed the tile will go down.

    private void Start()
    {
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        //The amount you want to go up on the Y component, for this example I used 2.
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 2f);

        StartCoroutine(MoveTileDown());
    }

    IEnumerator MoveTileDown()
    {
        while (transform.position.y > initialPosition.y)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, initialPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            yield return null; //Make it run every frame, just like Update()
        }

        StopCoroutine(MoveTileDown());
    }

}
```

There are a lot of ways you can achieve the same result, this is just one of them.